# format three strings into a good pattern

Tags: format, tcl

In Tcl I need to output the text in the following pattern:

[image]

The first column is string with different length, in fact the length difference is very big, and the second and third column are two numbers.

How to use format command to control the space length between the columns, then the head of each string can stand in the same vertical line?

Comment: Please post your attempt next time. You already know that you have to use the `format` function, you could at least put the attempted code in the question. As it is, it looks like a code request, which is not the purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: The [`parray`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/library.htm#M13) proc does this exactly. See how it is implemented: http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/a0b1bd4e68dce176

Answer (score 2):

First you need to compute expected column width. Then use [format](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm) to compose the string.

Use `-` flag for left-justification.

For example:

```
puts [format "%-30s %-10s %-10s" "Column1" "Column2" "Column3"]
puts [format "%-30s %-10d %-10d" "Ben" 23 234]
puts [format "%-30s %-10d %-10d" "Afasdfasdasd" 344 324534]
```

can get

```
Column1                        Column2    Column3
Ben                            23         234
Afasdfasdasd                   344        324534
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more question, does the format result can be supported by the text TK widget. For example, I use 
`set format_item [format "%-30s %-10s %-10s" "Column1" "Column2" "Column3"]` 
and `.text_area insert end "$format_item\n";` But it seems the format is not as expected.

Comment: @baoqger For the text widget, either use tabs or fixed-width fonts.

Comment: @baoqger If I were using Tk to display this kind of thing, I'd use [tablelist](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tablelist). Using a text widget is quite possible, but once you've got a tablelist widget set up, it's a great deal easier.